# c# Filter a response (MongoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, filtering

I'm filtering a MongoDB collection documents for the field "orderID" and the response looks like this: `{ "orderID" : "88996940" },{ "orderID" : "88996961" }`

how can I get only the value of the field like for example `"88996940","88996961"` ?

this is what my code looks like:

```
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("filter", "filter");
   
        var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id")
                                                          .Include("orderID");

        var find = await MyCollection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToListAsync();
        
        var combinedFind = string.Join(",", find);

        MessageBox.Show($"{combinedFind}", "all orders");
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this in one line:

```cs
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", find.Select(doc => doc.orderID)), "all orders");
```

And [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZQhtI) is an example with the result.